# Hibernate and JPA won't map to subclass when retrieved object through JPQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, jpql

I have a college project about web design. We're using Hibernate, JPA and Srpring framework.
I got an abstract superclass for actors of the system (Actor.java) which has a relationship with Message.java. My problem comes whenever a try to execute the following JPQL query: "select m from Message m", to retrieve the messages stored in the database (MySQL). It should return the messages, however it returns the following message:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find domain.Actor with id 3759
```

The messages are correctly stored in the database and as far as I'm concerned Java should map actors to their subclasses. And the subclass of Actor (Administrator.java) that has that id is also correctly stored

How can I properly correct this error?

By the way, here are the classes Actor and Message (every entity in my project extends DomainEntity which contains the necessary id, version, ...,  attributes).

Actor:

```
package domain;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

import security.UserAccount;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Actor extends DomainEntity {

    //Atributos --------------------------
    private String                      name;
    private String                      surname;
    private String                      email;
    private PhoneNumber                 phone;
    private String                      address;
    private int                         suspicious;

    //Relaciones -------------------------
    private Collection<SocialIdentity>  socialIdentities;
    private Collection<Folder>          folders;

    private Collection<UserAccount>     userAccounts;


    @NotBlank
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(final String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }
    public void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Valid
    public PhoneNumber getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(final PhoneNumber phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }
    public void setAddress(final String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Range(min = 0, max = 1)
    public int getSuspicious() {
        return this.suspicious;
    }

    public void setSuspicious(final int suspicious) {
        this.suspicious = suspicious;
    }
    @OneToMany
    public Collection<SocialIdentity> getSocialIdentities() {
        return this.socialIdentities;
    }
    public void setSocialIdentities(final Collection<SocialIdentity> socialIdentities) {
        this.socialIdentities = socialIdentities;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    @OneToMany
    public Collection<Folder> getFolders() {
        return this.folders;
    }
    public void setFolders(final Collection<Folder> folders) {
        this.folders = folders;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Collection<UserAccount> getUserAccounts() {
        return this.userAccounts;
    }

    public void setUserAccounts(final Collection<UserAccount> userAccounts) {
        this.userAccounts = userAccounts;
    }

}
```

And Message:

```
package domain;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Message extends DomainEntity {

    //Atributos -----------------------
    private Date                moment;
    private String              subject;
    private String              body;
    private String              priority;

    //Relaciones ----------------------
    private Actor               sender;
    private Actor               recipient;
    private Collection<Folder>  folders;


    @NotNull
    @Past
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getMoment() {
        return this.moment;
    }
    public void setMoment(final Date moment) {
        this.moment = moment;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getSubject() {
        return this.subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(final String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }
    public void setBody(final String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Pattern(regexp = "^HIGH|NEUTRAL|LOW$")
    public String getPriority() {
        return this.priority;
    }
    public void setPriority(final String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Actor getSender() {
        return this.sender;
    }
    public void setSender(final Actor sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Actor getRecipient() {
        return this.recipient;
    }
    public void setRecipient(final Actor recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }
    @ManyToMany
    public Collection<Folder> getFolders() {
        return this.folders;
    }
    public void setFolders(final Collection<Folder> folder) {
        this.folders = folder;
    }

}
```

Here is also the relevan content of the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Java compiler -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <Xlint />
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Population -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>utilities.PopulateDatabase</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Tomcat 7 -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
                <port>8080</port>
                <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Repositories to download components -->

<repositories>

    <!-- Spring repository -->

    <repository>
        <id>springsource</id>
        <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Apache repository -->

    <repository>
        <id>apache</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Default repository -->

    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<!--  Dependencies -->

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Framework -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>                                  
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Framework - Data -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Framework - Security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Framework - Testing -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Javax -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Display Tag -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Standard taglibs -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>           
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency patches -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

P.S: I'm very newbie with this technology.

Administrator.java

```
package domain;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Administrator extends Actor {

}
```

DomainEntity.java

```
package domain;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class DomainEntity {

// Constructors -----------------------------------------------------------

public DomainEntity() {
    super();
}


// Identification ---------------------------------------------------------

private int id;
private int version;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Version
public int getVersion() {
    return this.version;
}

public void setVersion(final int version) {
    this.version = version;
}

// Object interface -------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.getId();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object other) {
    boolean result;

    if (this == other)
        result = true;
    else if (other == null)
        result = false;
    else if (other instanceof Integer)
        result = (this.getId() == (Integer) other);
    else if (!this.getClass().isInstance(other))
        result = false;
    else
        result = (this.getId() == ((DomainEntity) other).getId());

    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result;

    result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(this.getClass().getName());
    result.append("{");
    result.append("id=");
    result.append(this.getId());
    result.append(", version=");
    result.append(this.getVersion());
    result.append("}");

    return result.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Just read the error message. There is a message referencing an actor with ID 3759, but this actor doesn't exist in the database. This means your database is corrupted, probably because you didn't add the required foreign key constraints, and removed this actor although it's referenced by a message. Clean up your data, and add the foreign key constraints so this this never happens again.

Comment: I edit, Actor subclasses are Administrator and Manager, and there is an Administrator with ID 3759, the database is not corrupted, the problem is with the mapping.

Comment: Then show the relevant code. How is the Administrator class defined? What are the tables involved and in which table is the administrator with ID 3759 located?

Comment: I have just edited it, you can check it now. Administrator with ID 3759 is in its own table.

Comment: Your mapping uses the default inheritance strategy, which is SINGEL_TABLE. So administrators are supposed to be in the Actor table. Not in their own table. You'd need TABLE_PER_CLASS to define them in their own table. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

Comment: Oh, and DomainEntity should NOT be annotated with Inheritance and Entity. It should be annotated with MappedSuperclass. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

Comment: I've added DomainEntity.java that I forgot to include at first. As you can see it is already using TABLE_PER_CLASS.

Comment: That class is given by the professor and I can't modify them.

Comment: Then your teacher doesn't know what he's doing.